# Split a file into multiple based on selected lines

Tags: files, split

I have a file in which more than 50,000 lines are there. How can I split the file into two or more based on the selected lines?

Suppose I want to split a file from line 10,000 to line 40,000.

Comment: You mean you want get line from `10000` to `40000` and skip the rest?

Comment: @Gnouc Yes, i want to skip rest

Comment: @Aravind: See the link Ramesh gave.

Comment: What NIX platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk ' NR<=10000{ next}
NR<=40000{print > "out2.txt"; next} ' input.txt
```

Comment: That's a bit convoluted way to write `awk 'NR > 10000 && NR <= 40000' input.txt > out2.txt`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I have to confess - I thought the OP wanted three files originally. One for 0-10000, another for 10000-40000 and another for 40000 upwards.  I quickly edited when I realised I'd miss-read the post by deleting the offending `print` statements.  I should have edited properly or deleted the post really!

Answer (score 1):

If you want lines 1 to 9999 in one file, 10000 to 40000 in a second and the rest in a 3rd, you can use:

```
csplit -f file.out file.in 10000 40001
```

(will store in `file.out0{0,1,2}`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

```
 sed -n '10000,40000p' <infile
```

Comment: Better `sed '10000,$!d;40000q'` or `tail -n +10000 | head -n 30001` to stop reading after the 40000th line.